# loopback 3 creating only test database for mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopback

I exported NODE_ENV=local and defined my mongo datasource as follows in datasources.local.json

```
"mongo": {
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 27017,
  "url": "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb",
  "database": "mydb",
  "password": "",
  "name": "mongo",
  "user": "",
  "connector": "mongodb"
},
```

But the database name is getting created as 'test'.I also tried in datasources.json but it's still the same. I need the database name to be 'mydb'. Please help

Comment: _I need the database name to be 'mydb'_; You can achieve this at least in two different ways. 1. from the mongo shell use directly the keyword `use mydb` and that will automatically allocate the namespace and create the db for you. Or 2. you can do it dynamically using the driver to connect to your mongodb (as opposed to the mongo shell) while passing the localhost, port and db name as a string. Is this is what you are asking or you want to allocate your db name using some complicated function?

Comment: The database is created on first write operation, not on connection. Try to insert a document to any collection in `mydb` database. `test` database is the default one, created on installation of the database, not by your application.

Comment: @rags2riches I tried `use mydb` but it still writes to test. I don't want to use some complicated function, just `Model.create()` writes the data to the test db

Comment: @AlexBlex I also created mydb and created an empty collection. But the application still writes to test. Even though I dropped the test database, the application still creates the test database. So, I don't think its created on installation of mongo, the app itself is creating the test database

Comment: @LalithMohan can you please share some code to reproduce the issue? If you open your connection to `mongd` before running the application, and then from your shell you connect to your `mongod` and run `use whatever`, that by default will allocate the namespace `whatever` to your local db that can then be referenced with `db`.

Comment: Can you please close your app and open your `mongod` first, then open your mongo shell in a new terminal with the command `mongo`; can you tell me what is the message that you get in your shell when you do this? 
Also, always in your shell, can you type show dbs and tell me the output and then, issues these commands `use mydb` and `db`...tell me the results of these operations please

Answer (score 0):

What fixed the problem for me was to set the name of the object to "db" and not "mongo" or "mongods".

```
"db": {
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 27017,
  "url": "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb",
  "database": "mydb",
  "password": "",
  "name": "mongo",
  "user": "",
  "connector": "mongodb"
},
```